# Prove a vector property using line segment midpoints?

Tags: geometry, vectors

Let $a$ be the midpoint of the line segment $XY$ and $b$ be the midpoint of the line segment $VW$. Prove that $\vec{ab}=\frac{1}{2}(\vec{XV}+\vec{YW})$

I draw the following picture:

[image]

I draw an arrow connecting point $V$ and $a$. Then $\vec{Xa}-\vec{XV}=\vec{Va}$ (corrected). Furthermore, $\vec{Vb}=\frac{1}{2}\vec{VW}$.

I combine these two to get $\vec{ab}=\vec{Vb}-\vec{Va}=\frac{1}{2}\vec{VW}-\vec{XV}+\vec{Xa}$.

$\vec{Xa}=\frac{1}{2}\vec{XY}$, so:

$\vec{ab}=\vec{Vb}-\vec{Va}=\frac{1}{2}\vec{VW}-\vec{XV}+\frac{1}{2}\vec{XY}$.

Now $\vec{VW}-\vec{YW}=\vec{XY}$, so, after more simplification:

$\vec{ab}=\frac{1}{2}\vec{YW}+\vec{XV}$.

EDIT: Where do I proceed from here?

Comment: Your first error is in line 6.

Comment: You have an error right from the start: $\overrightarrow{XV}+\overrightarrow{Va}=\overrightarrow{Xa}$.

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima, Which is line 6?

Comment: @alkykom Now line 6 is correct.

Comment: @alkykom `I combine these two to get ...` That's wrong, check the signs when you expand $-\vec{Va}\,$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**hint**

$$\vec {XV}=\vec {Xa}+\vec {ab}+\vec {bV} $$

$$\vec {YW}=\vec {Ya}+\vec {ab}+\vec {bW} $$

sum and use the fact that
$$\vec {Xa}=-\vec {Ya} $$
and
$$\vec {bV}=-\vec {bW} $$

Comment: Is this a theorem? Why is it true?

Comment: @alkykom It is Chasles relation AB+BC+CD+DE=AE